# Sharepoint import version error

Tags: sharepoint, stsadm

We have a SharePoint server that is version something like 12.0.4 and we are trying to import a site collection that was exported from another SharePoint server.  The version there is somthing like 12.0.0.  We have the export but we no longer have access to the server.  How do we import the site from a lower version into a higher version?

We have tryed the stsadm import function but that is where we get the problem with the version mismatch.

has anyone experenced something like this?

Comment: and this is programming related how?

Comment: Development in SharePoint isn't always 100% programming related. Developers often have to function as both an administrator and a developer. Why go through the effort of calling this out, what do you accomplish?

Comment: Still, this would be better on serverfault.com or somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a better way, but here's what I would just do because it can be done in the background, simultaneously to doing other stuff...

OK, both are version 12, so that would probably be just a diff in Service Pack levels / hotfixes etc. Set up your clean SP environment anew, without any service packs, updates, patches etc. Check the version number. If lower than your export, gradually perform updates until the version number is just identical. Import, and only after testing your imported content optionally apply other updates as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

And you don't have access to the original content database either?
If you do have that, simply attach the content database from stsadm and it will upgrade the database for you on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article for a detailed list of what version numbers correspond to which updates and patches of SharePoint.

http://www.mindsharpblogs.com/penny/articles/481.aspx

Can you check the actual version numbers in your farm? 12.0.0.4 corresponds to the RTM and Beta versions of SharePoint.

Let us know the exact version numbers on both ends if possible (if the text is in the error), and maybe we can recommend a more detailed solution.